# Change arrow orientation in smart diagram

Tags: smartdiagram

How can I change the arrow orientation (rotate by 180°) of this smart diagram?

```
\smartdiagramset{set color list={blue!40!white, blue!40!white,blue!40!white, blue!40!white, blue!40!white}}
\smartdiagram[priority descriptive diagram]{text1, text2, text3, text4, text5}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I am sure that it is possible and people here will be happy to help. Giving a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/28557) explaining your problem would improve your chance of getting answers.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot find a better way to do this, other than appending/overwriting parts of the `tikz` style defined for the arrow inside the `priority descriptive diagram` styles defined by `smartdiagram`.

You need to insert `\tikzset{priority arrow/.append style={rotate=180,anchor=0,xshift=30,}}` somewhere before the `\smartdiagram[...]{...}` line.  This line does a few things.

1. it rotates 180 degrees (whereas the style defined is `rotate=90` degrees)
2. it anchors the arrow at a different point (`anchor=west` is default)
3. it shifts the arrow downward using `xshift=30` (you may need to adjust this manually, depending on the size of your diagram)

The MWE with these changes is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}

\smartdiagramset{set color list={blue!40!white, blue!40!white,blue!40!white, blue!40!white, blue!40!white}}
\tikzset{priority arrow/.append style={rotate=180,anchor=0,xshift=30,}}
\smartdiagram[priority descriptive diagram]{text1, text2, text3, text4, text5}

\end{document}
```

Which results in this:

[image: flipped arrow on smartdiagram's priority descriptive diagram]

Comment: how does one expand or contract the width of the blue boxes with the text [1-5] in them?

Comment: @3kstc I would recommend asking this as a new question.  It will get more views that way.  In the `smartdiagram` documentation under `priority descriptive diagram` implementation I found the keys that you need: `\smartdiagramset{module minimum height=2cm, description width=10cm,descriptive items y sep=3}`.  You would need to merge with anything that you already have in the `\smartdiagramset` arguments.  `descriptive items y sep` needs to be modified if the height is too large -- otherwise the boxes overlap.