# How do I shrink the 3 pillow boxes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, smartdiagram

I am new to smartdiagram. Used to use Tikz a bit but that was more than a few years ago. For some reason, I am baffled by my inability to easily shrink the width of the three red "pillow boxes" which have my three labels "Tasks", "Tools", and "Techniques".

Thanks for any suggestions.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % % to change font to the default style of sans serif:

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\newcommand{\col}{red}

\tikzfading[name=priorityarrowfadingdown,
top color=transparent!5,
bottom color=transparent!80
]

\tikzset{priority
arrow fill/.style={
  fill=gray,
  path fading=priorityarrowfadingdown
  }
}

\begin{scope}[
   start chain=c going above,
   node distance=2mm,
   local bounding box=a,
   ]

\foreach \t in {
    \textbf{TECHNIQUES},
    \textbf{TOOLS},
    \textbf{TASKS}}
  \node [description, drop shadow, on chain, align=center] {\t};

\end{scope}

\newcommand{\distancemodules}{4cm}

% draw big arrow on side
\node [priority arrow, left=12mm, rotate=180, transform shape, anchor=before tail] (f) at (a.north west) {}; % wdg: "left=7mm" is the distance btw the boxes and the arrow 

% draw ticks on big arrow
\foreach \i in {1,...,3}
   \draw [\col, line width=5pt]  (c-\i -| f.south) -- (c-\i -| f.north);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding `\smartdiagramset{description text width=2.5cm, description width=3cm}` before `\foreach` would do the work. These options are documented in [manual of `smartdiagrame`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/smartdiagram/smartdiagram.pdf), sec. 4.2.2. In addition, your code is still in `tikz` style, but not `smartdiagram` style.

Comment: @Wayne  please see if the answer helps

Comment: That worked perfectly. All too easy once you know the answer. Many thanks. Note that I have some clever answers from below. I will response to those as well. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same with `smartdiagram` --

http://mirror.iopb.res.in/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/smartdiagram/smartdiagram.pdf

page 18-19

The default `uparrow` is changed with the help of `tikzset`

```
\tikzset{priority arrow/.append style={rotate=180,anchor=0,xshift=30,}}
```

--it rotates 180 degrees (whereas the style defined is rotate=90 degrees)
--it anchors the arrow at a different point (anchor=west is default)
--it shifts the arrow downward using xshift=30 (you may need to adjust this manually, depending on the size of your diagram)

The size of boxes is changed with the help of `smartdiagramset`

```
\smartdiagramset{description text width=2.6cm, description width=1cm}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}
\tikzset{priority arrow/.append style={rotate=180,anchor=0,xshift=30,}}
\smartdiagramset{description text width=2.6cm, description width=1cm}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \smartdiagramset{
                    set color list={orange!50!red,orange!50!red,orange!50!red},
                    priority arrow width=2cm,
                    priority arrow height advance=2.2cm
                    }
    \smartdiagram[priority descriptive diagram]{
                    \textbf{TECHNIQUES},
                    \textbf{TOOLS},
                    \textbf{TASKS}
                }
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Thanks to --

[Change arrow orientation in smart diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464737/change-arrow-orientation-in-smart-diagram)

and

@muzimuzhi